# android - How to raise an event on drag on the screen

Tags: android, event-handling

Scenario: I have 3 imageviews,call these as A,B & C. these are placed one after the another(in series) on the screen. now if i  drag my finger from A to C,  event of imageview B should raise.
Please suggest.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a [GestureDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html) and supply the Maths of dragging from A to C. Then when that `MotionEvent` occurs, perform the event.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to handle the touch event (override `onTouchEvent` or `setOnTouchListener` of `View`; or override `onTouchEvent` of `Activity`), and do the following:

1. `getActionMasked` and check for `ACTION_DOWN`. Set a flag, say, `isDown = true`
2. `getActionMasked` and check `if(isDown && getActionMasked() == ACTION_MOVE)` and do your work.
3. Additionally in multi-touch mode, you may want to `getPointerCount` to handle multiple `ACTION_DOWN` events.